# Tengo problemas para obtener el número de capicuas de un arreglo con numeros aleatorios y no se porque no me funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Errores no me aparecen, creo que tengo todo bien en sintaxis y en caso de que me haya equivocado en algo de sintaxis me informan.

En el siguiente código les dejo varios comentarios para que se hagan una idea de lo que llevo y para que no se pongan a husmear de más para no quitarles mucho tiempo.

UN CAPICUA es todo numero que se puede leer igual ya sea de derecha a izquierda como de izquierda a derecha : EJemplo 303, 202, 555, 878...
NOTA: en el código limite a que los números aleatorios solo pueden ser números comprendidos entre 100 y 999 incluidos el 100 y el 999.

```js
    function ObtenerArregloAleatorio() //nombre de la funcion
 {
      var filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
      var columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);
      var numero = 0; // numero de primos(no interesa para mi pregunta)
   var primo = true;//simplemente para evitar hacer procesos innecesarios(de nuevo no interesa para mi pregunta)
   var perfect = 0;//numero de perfectos que basicamente es solo el 496 ya que solo manejo numeros del 100 al 999(de nuevo no interesa para mi pregunta)
   var capicuas = 0;// Aqui el numero de capicuas como lo declare
      document.write(" <table border='2'>  ");

      for (i = 1; i <= filas; i++) { //primer for, este para las filas
        document.write(" <tr>  ");
        for (j = 1; j <= columnas; j++) { // segundo for para las columnas
          var aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
    var cantidad = 0;
          if (aleatorio < 100) {
            aleatorio = aleatorio + 100;
          }
    if(aleatorio % 10 == aleatorio / 100) // en teoria en este if si es verdadera la sentencia deberia de ser un capicua pero por alguna razon no se suma
    {
      capicuas++;
    }
    if(aleatorio == 496)
    {
      perfect++;
    }
          document.write("<td>" + aleatorio + "</td>");
    for(n = 1; n < aleatorio/2; n++) // tercer for para saber la cantidad de primos
    {
      if(aleatorio % n == 0)
   {
     cantidad++;
   }
   if(cantidad == 2)
   {
     break;
   }
    }
    if(cantidad < 2)
    {
      numero++;
   primo = false;
    }
        }
        document.write(" </tr>  ");
      }
      document.write(" </table>  ");
   if(!primo)
   {
     document.write("El total de primos es de: "+ numero);
   }
   else
   {
     document.write("No hay primos");
   }
   document.write(". Cantidad de perfectos: " +perfect);
   document.write(". Cantidad de capicuas: " +capicuas); // aqui estoy imprimiendo los capicuas
    }
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="filas" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="columnas" /><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="ObtenerArregloAleatorio()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
```

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para utilizar _snippets_ y que se pueda probar en vivo tu código. Creo que hace falta que expliques qué es un capicúa. Un saludo.

Comment: Esta interesante. te pido un favor: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de con qué par de números debería dar una capicúa?

Comment: no se si e entendido fuera de que no se que es un `capicúa` pero con solo analizar por encima este condicional `if(aleatorio % 10 == aleatorio / 100)` esta claro que solo el numero 0 es capaz de esto ya que  la `division` de un numero jamas podra ser igual a su `resto`

Comment: bueno bryro entonces has la siguiente operación : 404 mod 10 y 404 / 100...

Comment: 404 mod 10 = 4 **es diferente a** 404 /100 = 4,04 este número no pasa la validación en el condicional `if(aleatorio % 10 == aleatorio / 100)`

Comment: entonces 404/100 = 4.04 en JavaScript? entonces eso lo explica por que no me da.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución, aun que no la mejor sería validar si el número es una capicúa de la siguiente manera:

```
//Compararemos la variable 'aleatorio'
if((aleatorio.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) === aleatorio.toString()){
    //Entonces debe ser una capicua
}
```

Lo que se hace es, convertir la variable `aleatorio` en un `String`, después lo convertimos en un `Array` usando el método `split`. Una vez hecho eso, usamos el método `reverse` para invertir los elementos del `array`, es decir

```
//Si aleatorio es 202, entonces una vez
//convertido a Array será
aleatorio = [2, 0, 2];
//Con el método reverse, invertimos la posición de los elementos
aleatorio = [2, 0, 2];
//Una vez hecho eso, unimos el Array para convertirlo en un string usando el
//método join, entonces aleatorio será
aleatorio = '202';

//Y por último lo comparamos
```

Espero y te funcione...

Answer (score 0):

Primero (Lo que yo creo ) es que la fórmula no está del todo bien ya que funcionaria solo en algunos casos. Ejemplo:

```
valor 101
Resto de 101 / 10 = 1.0
101 / 100 = 1.0
OK
```

Pero si pones otra capicúa como 202 no da:

```
valor 202
Resto de 2002 / 10 = 2.0
2002 / 100 = 2.02
No da, pese a que 202 es una capicúa.
```

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```
function palindromo(number){

    var res, temp, final = 0;
    var number = number
    temp = number;

    while(number > 0)
    {
        res = number % 10;
        number = parseInt(number / 10);
        final = final * 10 + res;
    }

    if(final == temp)
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}



   /* Y en tu función original */

   if(palindromo(aleatorio) == 1){

            capicuas++;
   }
```

Prueba a ver que pasa ( a mi me da varias capicúas por ejercicio)

Comment: bueno creo que de pronto no se aprecia mucho en el código, pero todos los números aleatorios están comprendidos entre 100 y 999 y de hay no mas... igualmente gracias Eduardo por intentar ayudar, pero sigo con el mismo problema, el número de capicúas no aumenta.

Comment: ok, tienes razón pero insisto con la cantidad de decimales ya que asi como esta no se dará la igualdad en un montón de casos 121 % 10 = 1.1 | 121 / 100 = 1.21, haz un ejercicio en excel o  con todas las posibles capicúas y como esta no te dará la igualdad.